# Multiple COUNTIFS, with variabel text and numbers and named ranges

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm after a way to combine these 2 COUNTIFS formulas. They both work independently but I can't seem to find a way to join them. I want it to say "Price Not Ready" when any of the total criteria for either formula aren't met. So if the criteria of one formula is TRUE then display text. If either of them aren't TRUE then display "Price Not Ready".

The text "short" and "long" are named ranges.

=IF(COUNTIF(Long,"*"&D8&"*"),If(countifs($E$5>1,$F$5>1),"Bullish","Price Not Ready"))

=IF(COUNTIF(Short,"*"&D8&"*"),If(countifs($E$5>1,$F$5>1),"Bearish","Price Not Ready"))

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make things easier by using AND to combine criteria. The result will be TRUE if all arguments joined via AND are TRUE. One possible solution would then be:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(Long,""&D8&""),If(countifs($E$5>1,$F$5>1))),"Bullish",AND(IF(COUNTIF(Short,""&D8&""),If(countifs($E$5>1,$F$5>1)))),"Bearish","Price Not Ready")
```

Please let me know if this works for you. If not I might need some more background on the initial arguments e.g. COUNTIF(Long,""&D8&"") 
I would be expect the result to be either TRUE or FALSE or numerically either 1 or 0 in order to work as first argument in an IF formula which is supposed to be a logical test / result.